# Powerpoint Font Family

Tags: powerpoint, birt

When I set the output format to 'pptx' on a birt report, it exports to a powerpoint file. Everything looks fine except for the font. It's always set to Lucida Sans. Is there anyway to keep the font family that was set in birt?

I'm using eclipse kepler and birt 4.3.1.

Comment: Do you get this wrong font using Eclipse designer, or a web application (if so is it a custom webapp or Eclipse WebViewer, ...)? What is the operating system of the machine where reports are generated? Does it work fine in PDF format?

Comment: Yes, everything else works fine. It's fine in the designer, application and pdf. Tried it with windows 7 and mac osx.

Comment: To give some more info: I use eclipse designer for the design file, and I use birt engine to generate the powerpoint file. No actuate or ihub or anything

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, in my context generating a .pptx with reportEngine API makes use of the expected fonts. Generally this kind of trouble is due to an invalid fontPath used by BIRT, but since you said a PDF report generated from your reportEngine is fine, it can't be the cause. I don't have any idea right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this [Link](http://developer.actuate.com/be/documentation/Manualsihub2/working-with-birt-viewers.pdf)  you can download manual for Actuate BIRT viewer. Your problem is resolved in details at pages 206-208. 
In BIRT viewer vulgaris you need to place RenderDefaults.cfg file inside

*org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.3.2.v20140225-1404.jar*

under path *org\eclipse\birt\report\engine\emitter\config\ppt(x)*.

I haven't tested this, yet. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to my problem. I use eclipse report designer for the .rptdesign file. Then I use the birtengine to generate a pdf or a powerpoint. I don't use Actuate Birt viewer. The birt engine exports a .pptx file

Comment: I understand that you don't use Actuate BIRT viewer. These parameters are applicable for 'plain' BIRT viewer, I know since i decompiled so called emitter and confirmed usage of parameters. Please specify which font converts to Lucida Sand in .ppt so I can test it at my environment (I cannot reproduce issue with Arial font on 4.3.2 BIRT viewer).

Comment: I use Arial on 4.3.1. I export it to pptx

Comment: I found the file. Am I creating a file called 'RenderDefaults.cfg' and putting it under 'org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/emitter/config/pptx'? In the manual for Birt viewer I don't see any parameters for PPT format that can be useful other than 'FontSubstitution'. I don't see anything for PPTX

Comment: Yes, the path you wrote but inside the runtime jar.  I think that FontSubstitution=false would be enough. Sorry, didn't get the chance to test it.

Comment: So I extracted the jar file, put these files in, but now eclipse can't read the jar file. I'm using mac osx 10.9.3. I tried jar cf, it didn't work. I compressed the file as zip, and then renamed it to .jar, didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: jar problem solved. But it didn't work. I put it in the jar under "org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/emitter/config/ppt". I also put it under "org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/emitter/config/pptx" just in case, but no good

Comment: Just found out this doesn't happen if I run the app locally on my machine (mac osx 10.9.3). If the app is running on the server, and I access it through my browser, then it'll convert the fonts.

Comment: so looks like font doesn't exists on the server